# Reformatting Biblatex to have a Format like Natbib?

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I am using biblatex and have to get my literature displayed as below. For now I use :

```
\usepackage[              
              %citestyle=authoryear,
              %citestyle = alphabetic,
              %bibstyle=authoryear,
              %stylename = {numeric, alphabetic, authoryear, authortitle, verbose, reading, draft} 
              style=authoryear,%style=alphabetic,           
              autocite=footnote,              
              sorting=anyt,                  %anyt: Sort by first! name, year, title; %nty: Sort by name, title, year; % nyt: Sort by name, year, title.      
              % sorting = none (bei style=numeric) führt zu Sortierung nach Auftreten im Text
              maxcitenames=1, % Anzahl der Autoren
              maxalphanames=1, % Anzahl der Autoren im Kürzel
              maxbibnames=99,
              natbib=true, % natbib-Kompatibilitätsmodul für \citet, \citep
              uniquelist=false,
              %uniquename=false,
              %dashed=false, % Autoren mit gleichen Namen werden korrekt angezeigt!
              backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

And it provides me with the authoyear style. Is there a way to get the exact from below without switching to natbib?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `natbib` is primarily a citation management package. As such, it does not affect the appearance of the formatted bibliographic entries. (Well, there *are* a few natbib-provided ways to affect the spacing between entries and the amount of hanging indentation, but no more.) The formatting of the bibliographic entries is determined mostly by the bibliography style that's in use. The `natbib` package does provide a small number of bibliography styles, e.g., `plainnat`, `abbrvnat`, and `unsrtnat`. However, none of these styles produces formatted output even remotely (*continued in next comment*)

Comment: (*continued from previous comment*) similar to that shown in your screenshot. Would you know which bibliography style was employed to generate the screenshot?

Comment: some of the styles from the biblatex-archaeology bundle produce similar styles, e.g. jb-halle or nnu.

Comment: I do not know which style was used, sorry. I will try Ulrikes suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There are very few `biblatex` styles on CTAN that try to reproduce the behaviour of existing BibTeX styles. (There is `biblatex-trad`, which reproduces the output of the standard BibTeX styles `plain`, `abbrv`, `alpha`, `unsrt`. Then there are styles like `biblatex-apa6` or `biblatex-bath` that produce an output according to a well-known style guide for which there is also a BibTeX implementation - in this case `apacite` and `bath-bst`, respectively.) But for the vast majority of `.bst` styles there is no equivalent `biblatex` style.

If you want the exact output of an existing BibTeX style, your best bet is to just not use `biblatex` for that document and go with BibTeX.

If you are OK with capturing just the main aspects of a style and don't mind deviations in details, you can usually cook something up with `biblatex` and a bit of time. That's the beauty of `biblatex`: It is pretty flexible.

The following can get you started.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
  introcite=plain,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\\}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  and              = {u\adddot},
  backrefpage      = {zitiert auf S\adddot},
  backrefpages     = {zitiert auf S\adddot},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{%
  \ifcitation
    {\@firstofone}
    {\textsc}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}


\renewcommand*{\bibpagerefpunct}{\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pageref}{{\itshape\small#1}}
\newbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[pageref]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{nussbaum,aksin}
sit \autocite{westfahl:frontier}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson u. Ryde 1998 Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf: „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P Zitiert auf S. 1.]